# Sql statement condition in where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a problem in creating a where statement condition for below sql query.

I Wish to add a where condition not to display `num1` and `num2` value if both of them equals to zero or even any one of them equal to zero as well

```
SELECT Num1, Num2
FROM Position
WHERE  (Num1 IS NOT NULL AND Num2 IS > NOT NULL)
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC ;
```

Result:

```
    +---------+---------+
    | Num1    | Num2    |
    +---------+---------+
    |
    | 47.3941 | 8.68005 |
    |       0 |       0 |
    | 47.4385 | 8.61106 |
    | 47.4385 | 8.61106 |
```

Comment: Seems like a very simple requirement, what's the issue?

Comment: i just want  to add sql statment in where condition where num1 and num2 both not equl to zero or any one of them not equl to zero as well

Comment: Simply `where num1 > 0 and num2 > 0`.

Comment: @jarlh, what about `-9`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, whatever, couldn't find that row. `where num1 <> 0 and num2 <> 0`.

Comment: To clarify the question, please provide sample input and output.  It must have several lines in order to include _all_ 16 combinations of 0, NULL, positive, negative values for num1 and num2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following using [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT Num1, Num2 
FROM Position 
WHERE IFNULL(Num1, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(Num2, 0) <> 0
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a441a/1/0

***Explanation:*** You don't want to show a row if both values (`Num1` and `Num2`) are 0 (or NULL) or if one of these values (`Num1` or `Num2`) is 0 (or NULL). So you only want to show rows where both values (`Num1` and `Num2`) have a value unequal 0 (and NULL). So you can use `Num1 <> 0 AND Num2 <> 0` as condition. To set a default value for NULL you can use `IFNULL` (the second parameter is the value which will be used instead of NULL). In MySQL there should not be a difference between `IFNULL(Num1, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(Num2, 0) <> 0` and `Num1 <> 0 AND Num2 <> 0`

> **extended demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11f2a5/1/1

Comment: it work perfectly as i need . but can u please explain a bit .. i couldnt understand how that expression works

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 SELECT Num1, Num2 
    FROM Position 
    WHERE Num1 <> 0  
    OR Num2 <> 0
    ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a straight forward `<>` operator:

```
SELECT   Num1, Num2 
FROM     Position
WHERE    Num1 IS NOT NULL AND Num1 <> 0 AND
         Num2 IS NOT NULL AND Num2 <> 0
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC
```

You could also use `coalesce` to make the query a tad more elegant, although this is probably a question of personal taste:

```
SELECT   Num1, Num2 
FROM     Position
WHERE    COALESCE(Num1, 0) <> 0 AND
         COALESCE(Num2. 0) <> 0
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC
```

Comment: You can skip the NOT NULL stuff. `<> 0` is only true for non-null values.

Comment: For performance it's not advisable to use functions in a `where` clause anyway.

Comment: does it function for num1 and num2 either both are zero  or any one of them is zero as well

Comment: @tomtom look at the usage of the `and` logical operator. If either of them is `0`, the row won't be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change your query to:

```
SELECT num1, num2
FROM position
WHERE num1 <> 0 AND num2 <> 0
ORDER BY positiondatetime DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try : Where Num1<>0 and Num2<>0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Num1, Num2 
FROM Position 
WHERE (Num1 is not null and Num2 is not null)
ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT Num1, Num2 
    FROM Position WHERE Num1 <> 0 AND Num1 IS NOT NULL AND Num1 <> ''
    AND Num2 <> 0 AND Num2 IS NOT NULL AND Num2 <> ''
    ORDER BY PositionDateTime DESC ;
```

Comment: Though your code may solve the problem, please also provide some explanation as to why.